# Sails.js find doesn't work with or and select together

Tags: sails.js

I've made a simple code that was supposed to find several users that worked:

```
  Users.find({
      where: {country: req.param('country'), join: true},
      select: ['uid']

    })
```

when I changed the `where` to `or` as in the example below I started getting an error.

```
  Users.find({
      or: [{country: req.param('country'), join: true},{isAdmin: true}],
      select: ['uid']

    }).then()...
```

Using `select` works with `where` but not with `or`. I get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'req' of undefined
```

Comment: You might have to chain the where after the find? As in, `Users.find(...).where(...)`

Answer (score 0):

As Michael said I chained the `where` so now it works:

```
Users.find({
      select: ['uid','username','fbProfile','profilePic','phone']
    }).where({
      or: [{country: req.param('country'), join: true},{isAdmin: true}]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, `OR` is an operator for the `WHERE` clause and so should be nested within.  You could curry the clause as stated in the other answer, but you should also restructure your object to call it as so:

```
let localAdmins = await Users.find({
  select: 'uid',
  where: {
    or: [
      {country: req.param('country'), join: true},
      {isAdmin: true}
    ]
  }
});
```